# Mac OSX Finder file search for: -1. = no results... EVER

Tags: macos

Let's say I have a folder on my desktop with the following files:

file_c.txt

file_c-1.txt

file_b.txt

file_b-1.txt

file_a.txt

file_a-1.txt

Then, I do a finder search, in the folder, looking at the filenames and not the content.

If I enter a search criteria of: -1.

I get NO results!

Also, I cannot seem to find ANY documentation on escaping, wildcarding, or anything on the search function inside a folder....

Does anyone know how to search for this type of filename? I have a client that I have to constantly filter out these types of files from the contents of a folder on my desktop, so it would be REALLY helpful to simply search for them and delete them en mass.

Anyone run into this before? And how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the search string in quotes: "-1." which now should give the result you want.

I banged my head on a desk for a long time before I figured this one out by accident.

I also count'd find anything online... weird.